# Delete Query on Oracle Database taking time

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I have a query like this.

```
DELETE FROM ExampleTable WHERE pdate <= (select max(date) from table2 )
```

It is taking too much time to execute (around 20 mins).

Does it make a difference if I create Index on column pdate on the fly and execute the query. After successful execution, I drop the index.

Can we add any hints in the query to make it faster like we do in Insert APPEND hint ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If delete no more than 15% rows(It's approximately count) then index will help you.
For me I create partition on table with partition section on pdate. Looking at you query I assume that you delete old data.

Look at this brief explanation https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/partitioned-tables-and-indexes